# Can mmap library function be used in C and Assembler?

Tags: c, assembly, raspberry-pi, mmap

I am learning both C and Assembler(for Raspberry Pi 2) and I am trying to figure out how mmap works and if I can use it in both C and Assembler programs

Comment: You can call mmap from an assembler program but to fair you don't want to do that.

Comment: @user6556709 Why not?  `mmap` is a perfectly fine system call.

Comment: Yes, you can call `mmap` from both C and assembly programs.  This applies to every system call.   You can also call arbitrary library functions from assembly code, but then you have to link in the appropriate libraries.  If you let me know which operating system you are programming for and give me an example of how you want to call `mmap`, I can post some example code if you are interested in that sort of thing.

Comment: @fuz As I said you can. The point that you don't want to do it is that it becomes really fast very ugly and you didn't even have a chance to win anything against a C compiler.

Comment: @user6556709 Some times, it's not about winning, but rather about writing programs in assembly for the fun in it.

Comment: @user6556709: how do you know what optimizations might be possible in the OP's asm from inlining a system call and taking advantage of the fact that the system-call calling convention doesn't clobber any of the arg registers?  Maybe the `fd` or `length` args are useful later, and don't need to be stashed in another register if you use an `svc` instruction instead of calling the libc wrapper.  (But `mmap` is kind of a special case because it already has 6 args, but largefile support needs more than a 32-bit `offset` on a 32-bit platform.  See the `mmap2` system call: scaled `offset`.)

Comment: Peter Cordes; depends on target. Afaik on *BSD off_t is always 64-bit.

Comment: @Peter - I don't agree with the sentiment of "mmap is pointless in assembly" but to be fair I think the optimization you suggest effectively "rounds to zero" in the context of a mmap call that takes in the high hundreds or thousands of cycles :).

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: I think largefile is on by default for 32-bit Linux as well, but the Linux system-call calling convention (on any platform) only has room for 6 registers of args to system calls.  IDK what system-call calling convention *BSD uses on ARM.  On 32-bit x86, FreeBSD passes system call args on the user-space stack, so it's plausible that really does pass a 64-bit `off_t`.  But IDK what it actually does.

Comment: While the "mastodonts" are busy discussing the finest technicalities, I'm tempted to actually give an answer to the question in the title )) But that wouldn't have much value until the question is changed to "how?". To OP you can surely call anything from assembly that can be called from any other language. @fuz: I would expect Linux on Raspberry Pi 2

Comment: @tum_ I stopped making assumptions on this site.  This is why I ask for details before writing answers.

Comment: @fuz `stopped making assumptions` - and I can clearly see why ) Actually, I simply wasn't aware that there were non-Linux OS's available for Rasp Pi2 until I googled a few minutes ago..

Comment: @tum_ okay so how does using mmap for gpio pins in C differ from using it in assembler for the same purpose?

Comment: @yyyhtya I have no idea ;) Except that in C you use C and in assembly you use assembly to do what you want to do. Look, why don't you use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55974791/edit) link under your question and re-phrase it in a way that people can give you a proper answer. (Don't forget to specify the OS and whatever else people asked you to clarify). There are rules here.

Comment: @yyyhtya There isn't really a difference.  You just call `mmap` like you'd call a normal function.